# Github GraphQL Repository Query, using two objects

Tags: graphql, github-graphql

How to use more than one objects when querying Github GraphQL?

The following will break if the 2nd object is uncommented:

```
query {
  repository(owner:"rails", name:"rails") {
    object(expression:"master") {
      ... on Commit {
        history {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
    # object(expression: "master:README.md") {... on Blob {byteSize}}
  }
}
```

How to make it working? Thx

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), FYI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **alias**:

```
query {
  repository(owner:"rails", name:"rails") {
    object(expression:"master") {
      ... on Commit {
        history {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    },
    second_object: object(expression: "master:README.md") {... on Blob {byteSize}}
  }
}
```